# vs 2005 and vwd 2008

Tags: visual-studio

Can i open Visual Web developer 2008 projects with Visual studio 2005?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the VS project files are not backward compatible. But there is no reason why you cannot create a new VS2005 project file and add the various code files to it, and maintain it separately. Synchronizing the 2008 and 2005 project files is not hard, just use a diff tool like SourceGear's DiffMerge* to compare them and move the relevant lines back and forth between the two, you need to pay attention to the `Reference` and `Compile` ones:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="some assembly" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="some code file.cs"></Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

I don't know why you would want to go back to VS2005 if you have access to VS2008 though.

*this is not your only option, there are heaps of good diffing tools out there